# Get name of worksheet selected using Application.Inputbox

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, inputbox

I want to get the name of the worksheet I selected.

I tried this code from ChatGPT.

```vb
Sub GetSelectedWorksheetName()

    Dim selectedSheet As Worksheet

    Dim selectedSheetName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedSheet = Application.InputBox("Select a worksheet", Type:=8).Worksheet

    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not selectedSheet Is Nothing Then
        selectedSheetName = selectedSheet.Name
        MsgBox "Selected worksheet name: " & selectedSheetName

    Else
        MsgBox "No worksheet selected."
    End If
End Sub
```

I received this error message.
[image]

Comment: The code runs ok. As the message says, the problem is with some formula. You can locate the problematic cell or cells from menu Types -> error checking

Comment: What do you write in the input box exactly?

Comment: I have a worksheet where the source date is for data analysis - i want to set a dynamic range for instance code be like set SourceData = sheets(SelectedSheet.Name).range("A1").CurrentRegion. However, the selected sheet could be any name depending on how other user define it, so i thougtht by using ApplicaitonInputBox with type 8 would allow me to capture the name of that Source Sheet that i click .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the inputbox expects a range (i.e. one or more selected cells), you/user need(s) to select that and not just the sheet. See [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) for the different types and what they expect.

So to make your code work as intended, select a range in the sheet and not only the sheet and adjust your code as follows:

```
Sub GetSelectedWorksheetName()

    Dim selectedSheet As Worksheet
    Dim selectedSheetName As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set selectedSheet = Application.InputBox("Select a worksheet", Type:=8).Parent
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not selectedSheet Is Nothing Then
        selectedSheetName = selectedSheet.Name
        MsgBox "Selected worksheet name: " & selectedSheetName
    Else
        MsgBox "No worksheet selected."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I now understood why i was getting the error message before as i only selected the sheet and nothing else. As you explained, i needed to select the sheet and as well a cell in that sheet! that had puzzled me the whole night. Thank you

Comment: and also i have found this line application.screenupdating = false which locates in the beginning of my codes, would somehow prevent the application.inputbox's ability for user to go in to the sheet they need to select a cell.

Comment: It's good to keep track of those things, yeah, easily overlooked when you're used to putting them at the beginning.